# VBA : How to display two ComboBox on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, adodb

I would like to display 2 ComboBox on the same sheet. For this I have 2 ADODB sql requests that I run subsequently. This function are running while Workbook is openning. When I test only the first function, Liste1, the time is OK, but when I am running two functions the time is too long. I don't know how to improve my code. Thank you for your help !

My code is :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Liste1
Call Liste_Mandataire
End Sub




Private Sub Liste1()
CONTRAT_VALID = False

Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
Call CONNEXION_PEGASE("XXX", "XXX", "XXX")

RECSET.Open "select  distinct (pers.S_RAISONSOC||' - '||tiers.CD_TIERS) as cible, tiers.CD_TIERS as tiers  from db_protocole proto, db_tiers tiers, db_personne pers" & _
            " where pers.S_RAISONSOC not like '%NE PLUS UTILISER%' and proto.is_tiers = tiers.is_tiers and pers.is_personne = tiers.is_personne ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
While Not RECSET.EOF
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Liste_cible.AddItem RECSET!cible

RECSET.MoveNext
Wend
RECSET.Close
Call DECONNEXION_PEGASE
End Sub

Private Sub Liste_Mandataire()
CONTRAT_VALID = False
Dim RECSET As New ADODB.Recordset
Call CONNEXION_PEGASE("XXX", "XXX", "XXX")

RECSET.Open "select  distinct (pers.S_RAISONSOC) as mandataire from db_protocole proto, db_tiers tiers, db_personne pers, db_portefeuille portef" & _
            " where pers.S_RAISONSOC not like '%NE PLUS UTILISER%' and portef.IS_TIERS_GESTIONNAIRE = tiers.is_tiers and pers.is_personne = tiers.is_personne ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
While Not RECSET.EOF
Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Liste_Mandataire.AddItem RECSET!mandataire

RECSET.MoveNext
Wend
RECSET.Close
Call DECONNEXION_PEGASE
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there more items in the second list?  Have you tried timing each sub to see how long they take?  It may be that the second query just takes longer to complete...

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you, maybe there is some other way to organize this queries ?

Comment: Have you tried using `Get Data` in Excel to collect the data automatically? Import the query results in to a query tab and then just cite those ranges to populate your comboboxen: https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/the-complete-guide-to-power-query/

Comment: @HackSlash Thank you, but I can't, I have the restriction to a server.

Comment: @HackSlash I'm wondering if I can reorganize these queries in a more efficient way.

Comment: You can use Get Data to connect to a server. That was the original intent of the feature. It will be superior to attempting to reinvent the wheel in VBA.

Comment: @HackSlash, Interesting, I'll try to do that. Thank you !

Comment: @TimWilliams I found the anomaly in my adodb sql query: I had extra data in Liste_Mandataire." db_protocole proto" wasn't using in joins. After deleting this data, I have less processing time. If we have "too much" data in the query (which we don't really use in joins), the processing becomes slowly ?

Comment: @HackSlash I found the anomaly in my adodb sql query: I had extra data in Liste_Mandataire." db_protocole proto" wasn't using in joins. After deleting this data, I have less processing time. If we have "too much" data in the query (which we don't really use in joins), the processing becomes slowly ? –

Comment: Yes you’d expect more records to take longer to retrieve and add to the list